# Python / Selenium How to click 0,0 of the selected element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have:

```
x = b.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//body'))
if x:
     x[0].click()
```

When I click body (as an empty space to close some customer select dropdown) it will click at the centre of the element, which actually clicks one of the options from the drop-down list.

Question: How to click (at 0,0) point of the selected element (so it will click in the left top corner of the element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done with Selenium `.click()` method but this do can be done with `ActionChains`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 3, 3)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

This will move the mouse 3 pixels down and 3 pixels right from the upper-left corner of the element `el` you passing here and perform a click there.

Comment: Thank you, please change action to actions ;)

Comment: Ah, sure. thank you for fixing the copy-paste typo :)

Comment: I hope this resolved your problem?

Comment: It is, I really through it can be done without actionChains

Comment: Well, maybe there is some other approach, like some kind of JavaScript, I don't know. But I do not know how to do that with normal Selenium click